# Cesium labels on a polyline (similiar to a textpath)?

Tags: d3.js, svg, leaflet, mapbox, cesiumjs

I would like to recreate bent country labels according to the area of the country.

In d3 (or SVG) I can construct a polyline and then use a textpath to have text along it. Example: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/images/text/text-path-startoffset.svg

Is it possible in Cesium to do something similar?

In Leaflet it is implemented like that: http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.TextPath/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no native support for that in the current version of Cesium.  It may be mentioned on a wishlist or on a roadmap somewhere, but there are no short-term plans that I know of to add it to Cesium.

Even so, you may be able to find a workaround.  For example, SVGs can be used as texturemap image sources in Cesium, so you could possibly use D3 to produce curved text on-the-fly and load the results into a Cesium billboard image or even a Cesium Globe inlay image.  It would probably take some experimenting to figure out how to actually wire this up and how well it would work.

Comment: Thanks! I am currently experimenting with several graphics in which I use a canvas (textpath drawn on it) as material. Billboards don't seem to work because they are not static and follow the camera view - so it more likely will end up being a rectangle or a inlay image as you mentioned (need to benchmark those performances).